# import large number of .txt files to data.frame, include empty .txt files by giving them a row data.frame

Tags: r

I have a large number of .txt-files that I try to import in R. Some of the .txt-files are empty, but they I still want to include in my data.frame which .txt-files specifically are empty. With the following function I can import all necessary .txt-files to a list:

```
file_list <- list.files()
myList <- lapply(file_list, function(x) {tryCatch(read.table(x, header = F, sep = '|'), error=function(e) NULL)})
```

However, when I change this list into a data.frame with the following code:

```
myDataframe <- rbind.fill(lapply(myList, function(f) {as.data.frame(Filter(Negate(is.null), f))}))
```

I lose the information about which .txt-files were empty.

Ultimately, what I would like is that on each row a column is added with the name of the .txt-files, for example via list.files(). In that way, I could see which rows are empty.

Comment: Many thanks in advance for your time and thinking along :)!

Comment: Ok, if someone stumbles upon the same problem, the following worked for me:

library(plyr)
#make a data.frame and count the number of button presses per participant:
    file_list <- list.files()          #make list with all .txt-files                   
    myData <- lapply(file_list, function(x) {  #import info .txt-files into list
     tryCatch(read.table(x, header = F, sep = '|'), error=function(e) NULL)
    })

    count <- sapply(myData, NROW) #count all rows per list
     Rdata<-data.frame(file_list,count) #save in a vector how many rows were included

Answer (score 1):

This a solution to your problem, but not specifically an answer to your question.

Depending on the size of your text files. You should consider switching to `data.table`. A nifty system for handling large files rapidly and in a memory efficient manner.

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
file_list <- list.files()

Results <-  NULL
for (i in file_list){
  # data.table command to read txt files
  i.file <- tryCatch(fread(i,colClasses="character"), error=function(e) e)

  if(!class(i.file)[1]=="data.table"){
    # This condition checks that no errors occured
    i.file <- data.table(cbind(txt.file=i,is.empty="YES",
                         message=i.file$message))
  } else if(nrow(i.file)==0){
    # Just in case files are still empty even though no error
    i.file <- data.table(cbind(txt.file=i,is.empty="YES",
                         message=NA))
  } else {
    i.file[,txt.file:=i]
    i.file[,is.empty:="No"]
  }
  Results <- rbind(Results,i.file,fill=TRUE)
  rm(i.file);gc()
}

# to find which files are empty
Results[is.empty=="YES"][,txt.file]
# double check error types
Results[is.na(message)][,message] 
# expect all to be something like 'file is empty'

# if you insist on using data.frames
Results <- data.frame(Results)
```

This should work for you. The script may be converted to a function that works with lapply, but i wanted it to be easy to understand and generalize.

Also I'm a huge fan of `data.table` and transitioning to it was really helpful to me. For more on the package check out this [cheatsheet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf).

**EDIT:** Script modifed so it can accommodate empty files with whitespaces

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, it does not work: "Error in fread(i, colClasses = "character", verbose = TRUE) : 
  Input is either empty or fully whitespace after the skip or autostart. Run again with verbose=TRUE." I added 'verbose = T" but the error remained.

Comment: This error occurs because your 'empty' files are not entirely empty. They contain a whitespace. Now im not sure if this this is the case for all your 'empty' files or just a few of them so i've accounted for this in the edited script above.

Comment: The non-empty files. How many rows and columns are you expecting? if either is more than 1 then the edited script above should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I upvoted your answer but apparently my reputation is to low !

Comment: please tick check mark beside the answer so this question can be considered closed